# Does GCP assign sub domain name to vm instance?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I am new for GCP. I try to create vm instance but i cannot find domain name which AWS provide for ec2. Just want to check whether GCP provides temp/sub-domain for its instance or not. Thanks

Comment: As long as I know there is no subdomain assigned to GCP VM instances. We should access it via IP address or setup our own domain

Comment: @DharmaSaputra, noted. yup, I only find out GCP provides internal domain for mapping to the private ip address .[HOSTNAME].c.[PROJECT_ID].internal

Answer (score 0):

GCP does not provide sub-domain rather use internal domain [[HOSTNAME].c.[PROJECT_ID].internal](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/internal-dns#instance-fully-qualified-domain-names) within the GCP environment. You can address instances over the internal VPC network while using [HOSTNAME].c.[PROJECT_ID].internal